# OpenCV で画像を等分したい

Tags: python, opencv

opencvで画像を分割する際、１枚の画像を4つに分割して保存するには

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2

def main():

    '''
    # 2点(x1,y1),(x2,y2)を通る矩形部分を切り抜き
    clp = img[x1:x2, y1:y2]
    # クリッピングした箇所を保存
    cv2.imwrite("img.png", clp)   
    '''

    img = cv2.imread("test.png")
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    clp = img[0:height/2, 0:width/2]
    cv2.imwrite("test-tl.png", clp)

    clp = img[0:height/2, width/2:width]
    cv2.imwrite("test-tr.png", clp)

    clp = img[height/2:height, 0:width/2]
    cv2.imwrite("test-ul.png", clp)

    clp = img[height/2:height, width/2:width]
    cv2.imwrite("test-ur.png", clp)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

というコードで出来たのですが
これを縦２つ、横３つに画像を分ける場合はどのようにコードを変えればいいのでしょうか。
教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

縦と横それぞれでループする例です。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cv2

def main():
    img = cv2.imread("test.png")
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    height_split = 2
    width_split = 3
    new_img_height = int(height / height_split)
    new_img_width = int(width / width_split)

    for h in range(height_split):
        height_start = h * new_img_height
        height_end = height_start + new_img_height

        for w in range(width_split):
            width_start = w * new_img_width
            width_end = width_start + new_img_width

            file_name = "test_" + str(h) + "_" + str(w) + ".png"
            clp = img[height_start:height_end, width_start:width_end]
            cv2.imwrite(file_name, clp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: このプログラムのheight_splitとwidth_splitの値を変えれば、縦２つ横３つ以外の分割数にすることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: @user7341567 可能です。ただ、ピクセル数を `int` で切り捨てている所は、分割数が多かったり、元画像が小さかったりする場合には再検討が必要かもしれません。

Comment: 了解しました。ありがとうございました。